# Building and Deploying 64-bit from 32-bit Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, msbuild, 64-bit

We require unmanaged code for our project.  The project compiles and runs perfectly in our 32-bit environment. However, when we deploy to azure the project fails when trying to access the dll (32-bit and 64-bit).  It fails primarily because the compiled code is targeting 32-bit (system.intpr.size == 4) although its running on 64-bit azure.  Even though we are building with x64 from a 32-bit machine, the project still runs as 32-bit on azure.

Is there a way to build and deploy a 64-bit application to azure with our 32-bit machine or do we need to upgrade our machines to 64-bit?